# Sine to pulse converter circuit help

Tags: converter, ltspice

[image]

I have a sine to pulse converter box(LM2903 is used), it works very well and I also have the circuit schematics. The converter converts the mV level sinusoidal signals to pulses.

I want to rebuild it so first I drew it in LTSPICE but it doesn't work. It outputs constant negative voltage not pulse for given sinusoidal input signals.

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like 20 Hz @ 0.1 v?  How long are you simulating?

Comment: I tried 0.01V as well I simulate 1 sec or 10 sec both wont work. I get negative voltage.

Comment: ok it simulated in another software. check out: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203130/comparator-question-for-weak-sine-inputs

Comment: Interesting did you try the LTSPICE version without the 220 ohm load?

Comment: yes I tried it gives huge constant voltage n that case.

Comment: Have you set the model for U2 correctly? Upload the .asc file to pastebin... if you still care about this. Whose LM2903 have you used? Have you checked that the subckt pins match the order expected by LTspice... sometimes they don't. Can you make a much simpler comparator circuit work with that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I know why it's not working without even trying it. The 2903 has an open-collector output and you've tied the load to ground. It's possible you have some other error besides this though.

Comment: what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Tie the load (R6) between output and the supply V1 instead. See this similar (in that respect) question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201511/inverting-comp-behaving-strange

Comment: it still doesnt work i get constant output

Comment: @user16307: Then upload the asc file to pastebin. I don't feel like redrawing all of it.

Comment: which file? file for the comparator?

Comment: @user16307: for your circuit. The comparator is enough if you tell me where you got it from.

Comment: here: http://ltwiki.org/files/LTspiceIV/Vendor%20List/STMicroelectronics/Standard%20Linear%20ICs/Spice/lm2903.txt

Comment: @user16307: Do you have a matching `.asy` for that (ST model) in your LTspice? Because for example [TI's model of the same IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/slcj011) has the pins in *completely* different order. You need to create (or reuse) an `.asy` with matching pin order.

Comment: Also the [latest version of the same file from ST](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/ecad_models_and_symbols/hw_model/lm290x_spice.zip ) has the pins in different order than that wiki file (which is either and old copy or someone modified it for whatever reason). In fact, ST's latest version has the same pin order as TI's. I'm not gonna bother creating an asy for some random old file from the interwebz.

Comment: i have to leave my home urgently i get back to u later thanks

Comment: opened a related question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203409/low-level-sine-to-pulse-converter-with-sharp-rising-edges-question